# Dagger2 - Component hold as a static object in Application

Tags: java, android, dagger-2

In my `Application` class, I have my singleton Dagger `Component` as a static object and reach it via its static getter method.

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

        private static UtilsComponent utilsComponent;

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
           ......
        }

        public static UtilsComponent getUtilsComponent(){
            if(utilsComponent == null){
                utilsComponent = DaggerUtilsComponent.builder()
                        .formattersModule(new FormattersModule())
                        .build();
            }
            return utilsComponent;
        }
}
```

What I want to know is that is this the right way to do this? Can it cause problems? If so, what are those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's okayish. But why would you put it in the `Application` class? Put it in standard singleton class called for example `Injector`. Still you might want to initialize that singleton in `Application` which is fine.

Comment: Why would I want to initialize that singleton in `Application` class? Is there a specific reason for that?

Comment: To provide globlal (application) `Context`.

Answer (score 1):

It is ok, but you will not be able to use inject Context- dependent objects in that way. For component, requiring Context, use non - static accessor in Application class. 
Speaking more widely, there will be as many components as your want, but if if component provides @Singleton - annotated functionality, lifecycle of component should not be longer that one of feature using it.